# Looping in TableLayout and Getting Values of all Views

Tags: android, tablelayout

Hello in my table layout I have several table rows created dynamically.  Each row has about 5 views, 1 autocompletetextview and 4 edittext.

Now I have a button outside of the table layout, when a user clicks it I want to be able to loop through the table and get the values of each of the views.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I seem to have solved it with some help:

```
private void saveUserInput() {
    mWeekdays = new JSONArray();
    mSchedules = new JSONArray();

    for(int c = 0; c < mWeekdaysView.getChildCount(); c++)
    {
        View child = mWeekdaysView.getChildAt(c);
        if (child != null && child instanceof TableRow)
        {
            TableRow row = (TableRow) child;

            for(int i = 0; i < row.getChildCount(); i++) {
                View input = row.getChildAt(i);

                if (input != null && input instanceof CheckBox) {
                    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) input;

                    if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
                        mWeekdays.put(checkBox.getText().toString().toLowerCase());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for(int j = 0; j < mWeekdays.length(); j++) {


        for(int c = 0; c < mSchedulesView.getChildCount(); c++)
        {
            View child = mSchedulesView.getChildAt(c);
            if (child != null && child instanceof TableRow)
            {
                TableRow row = (TableRow) child;

                JSONObject schedule = new JSONObject();
                for(int i = 0; i < row.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    View input = row.getChildAt(i);

                    if (input != null && input instanceof EditText) {
                        try {
                            EditText editText = (EditText) input;
                            schedule.put(editText.getHint().toString().replace(" ", "_").toLowerCase(), editText.getText().toString());
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }

                try {
                    schedule.put("weekday", mWeekdays.getString(j));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                mSchedules.put(schedule);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

My only question now is why AutoCompleteTextView is interpreted as an EditText.